# facescontext is released before thread finish to work

Tags: java, jsf, facescontext

I am calling a thread from a backing bean that makes many db activities.
I want to add message to the context,
 but until i get to the end of the run() method the context is already released.
How can i add message to context inside run() method of thread ,
without depending on the bean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. you can do this with ajax push...
You can use prime faces or whatever you want to do the pushing...

You should make a bean for notifications.. and whenever you want to notify on the client (as you like) announce that bean somehow... think about it :)

In this way you can announce the client after 30 minutes that what he wanted is done...

In worst case scenario you can use "setInterval" function in javascript.. to periodically check a servlet for messages...

Here is [a tutorial for commet](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/#N100CC)..

More details about [comet here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

(Yes.. with ajax push is a pretty long way.. -  if you want to do it by yourself)

cheers.

Comment: in my web we don't use prime or ice .is there any other option you know?

Comment: you can use jQuery or something you want (even pure javascript - I suggest jQuery to everybody because is crossbrowser).. and do by yourself an ajax push... I think you can do this using a servlet.. Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) but I suggest you use primefaces only for the page you need :)

Comment: maybe you can link me an example because i don't know it very well?

Comment: here is an example of push: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf ... I will edit my post if I find an ajax push tutorial

Comment: my opinion is that you should use primefaces.. only for this scenario.. :)

Comment: RichFaces has ajax push support, too: RichFaces 3.3 (JSF 1.2): http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_push.html RichFaces 4 (JSF 2): http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/GettingStartedWithRichFaces40Push

Comment: Yes... You can use any implementation...

Answer (score 0):

The faces context instance is bound to the thread servicing the current request via a ThreadLocal. You may try retrieving the FacesContext instance and passing it as a variable to the thread before starting it.

Comment: i tried it and it is not working .

Comment: i'm assuming you are starting your threads in the invoke application phase? if so, do you wait for them to finish before returning a outcome string?

Comment: Apparently not, given the problems :)